# Use gulp locally outside node

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, local

I would like to use gulp in my Wordpress project. Is it possible to execute gulp functions outside a node JS project?

I'm running on OSx, but couldn't find anything on the internet about it. Or do I'll have to use another lib like Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the main language of your project doesn't affect whether or not your can include some `node.js` dependencies and run them. You will need to have gulp installed and have a `gulpfile.js` in your project, and then you can run it.

You could install gulp globally on the server (`npm install -g gulp`), but I recommend creating a `package.json` file (using `npm init`) in your project, so that your node.js dependencies are tracked in your version control, and installing gulp with `npm install --save gulp` (inside your project's directory). Since gulp won't be installed globally in that case, you will need to use `"$(npm bin)"/gulp` from a directory inside your project to run it.

Comment: Thanks didn't thought about this solution. Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Yeti Launch](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/yeti-launch.html) from the Zurb foundation for the same setup (no node installed on my Mac).

When you run it, it will create a Foundation frame but you can do the following:

1. Stop the project it creates from within its interface,
2. Delete the files it creates and replace with yours

   - Leave the project it shows in the interface
   - Leave the "node_modules" folder it creates
3. Start the project again

This will run your Gulp file.

The only issue is installing node modules. For this, I look at any error messages it gives regarding missing modules and copy these into the "node_modules" folder from Github

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is **no**. Gulp is distributed as a [npm package and has node.js as a dependency](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) BUT that doesn't mean you can't use it outside of a node.js project.

The only real need for Gulp on a wordpress project would likely either be at the theming layer or if you were doing a custom plugin. Assuming you are making a theme, some of them use Gulp extensively.

I've used the [Roots ecosystem's Sage theme](https://roots.io/sage/) successfully on a number of projects. It has node/npm dependencies but they are all included if you use the theme. Check out [their Gulp file](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/gulpfile.js) - it's probably close to what you are philosophically looking for.

Comment: Voted down because it is possible, sorry. But the Sage default theme looks good though. Beside that, I'm also a Wordpress theme developer and I want to use Grunt to watch my CSS & JS files and run a few other task. Thanks for replying and trying to help anyway.